# Does javascript have an equivalent to PHP's preg_replace_callback?

Tags: javascript, metabox

I have a php function that executes inside an add_meta_box() in the WP content editor (see below) that I would like to convert to javascript so that it executes on a button click (on demand vs automatic on load) to convert the post content in real time (without posting to the server).

Is there an equivalent method set in javascript?

```
add_meta_box('mycontentfilter', __('My Content Filter'), 'my_content_filter', 'post', 'side', 'high'); 

function my_content_filter()
{
    global $post;
    $mykeyword = 'find this phrase';
    $post->post_content = preg_replace_callback("/\b($mykeyword)\b/","doReplace", $post->post_content);
}


// the callback function
function doReplace($matches)
{
    static $count = 0;
    switch($count++) 
    {
        case 0: return '<b>'.$matches[1].'</b>';   // 1st instance, wrap in bold
        case 1: return '<em>'.$matches[1].'</em>'; // 2nd instance, wrap in italics
        case 2: return '<u>'.$matches[1].'</u>'; // 3rd instance, wrap in underline
        default: return $matches[1];              // don't change others.
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing personal, but I voted to close because this is indeed related to Javascript in general, not WordPress. Stack Overflow has [many questions on this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+regex). If you disagree, [please join the discussion on Meta](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100/should-we-allow-general-php-css-html-questions-if-theyre-contextually-related-to)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi **@Scott B**:

This is really more of a [**StackOverflow**](http://www.stackoverflow.com) question than a WordPress Answers question. I'll take a stab at it but if this is not what you need I'd suggest deleting your question here and putting it up at SO.

The `Replace()` function in Javascript can take a function as an argument. [Ben Nadel](http://www.bennadel.com/) *(who is a bonafide jQuery/Javascript rockstar, at least in my book)* has a great article covering how to use `Replace()` with a callback *(look for the subhead **"Javascript String Replace() - Function Replace"**):*

- [**Using Regular Expressions In Javascript (A General Overview)**](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1742-Using-Regular-Expressions-In-Javascript-A-General-Overview-.htm)

Comment: Example: "how now, brown cow".replace(/(o)(.)/g, function(match, first, next){ return first + next.toUpperCase(); }); // returns "hoW noW, broWn coW"